# how to implement SIP(Session Initiation Protocol) App in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, sip

Please give me simple code for SIP project. I have some sample code like Siphon, liphone but its not working properly so give me simple code for implement this project.

Comment: Please post your current code and ask specific questions. We won't write any code for you, if you don't put any effort in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Best library which implements `SIP` standart, in my opinion is `PJSIP`. It can be used with iOS too. Give it a [view](http://www.pjsip.org). It has a [simple demo](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm) which can make and receive calls.